# Stack Overflow mobile CSS and JavaScript framework

Tags: discussion, javascript, design, stack-overflow

What CSS framework (if any) does SO use for mobile devices? Do they also use jQuery?

Comment: What are you doing that you want this information? SO? GMail? Whats next? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199372/what-css-framework-does-gmail-for-mobile-use

Comment: Researching mobile frameworks. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: you can checkout their api https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DIY**

1. Install [user-agent switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) in FF
2. Change user agent to iPhone
3. Browse to SO
4. CTRL+U

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=3c808850d245"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/mobile.js?v=c58294e4b2d6"></script>
```

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/skins/mobile/all.css?v=691d8c3ee5fa">
```

Comment: Or click the 'mobile' link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @jjnguy how convenient